# Applying a transformation to UIBezierPath makes drawing disappear

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform

maybe this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to apply a transformation to a path as simple as this:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
path.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 2.0))
"colorLiteral".setFill()
path.fill()
```

And seems like the fact of adding the "apply" line, completely erases the shape on the view, whereas if I don't include that line, the shape appears on its place correctly.

I'm quite new at Swift so I guess I'm missing an important step on this?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and remember `rotationAngle` takes **Radians**.

```
let bounds = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -bounds.midX, y: -bounds.midY))
path.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 4))
path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY))
```

Comment: Okay, my mistake was not understanding that the transformation always happens from the origin point, not the path itself. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Using CATransform3D**

```
shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, -1, 1)
```

**Transforming path,**

```
let shapeBounds = shapeLayer.bounds
let mirror = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,
                                  y: -1)
let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,
                                  y: shapeBounds.size.height)
let concatenated = mirror.concatenating(translate)

bezierPath.apply(concatenated)

shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
```

**Transforming layer,**

```
let shapeFrame = CGRect(x: -120, y: 120, width: 350, height: 350)
let mirrorUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,
                                              y: -1)
shapeLayer.setAffineTransform(mirrorUpsideDown)
shapeLayer.frame = shapeFrame
```